# Conway game of life using Python Doesn't Update Correctly

Tags: python

please bear with me as I'm just learning classes in Python. I am recreating Conway's game of life in Python. I am struggling to figure out how to update the board (a nested array) - I am trying one board with only the original values and another board with updated values. My purpose in doing so is to keep the updated cells from influencing the other cells. Even though I update one board with values and not the other one, they end up having the same values.

In the code, 1 represents a live cell and 0 represents a dead cell. The main loop is at the bottom. The class `CheckState` accepts the two boards, `upboard` and `board` . As you can see in the function `rules`, `board` is not updated. However, `upboard` accepts the updated values in the function `liveordie`.When I printed both nested arrays out, however, they were the exact same. Please see my code so far below. I thought including the whole code would help clarify what I just tried to explain.

```
"""The game of life

Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by over-population.
Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
"""


cellCoords=[] #this list of original cells 

class setup:
    def __init__(self,size,cells):
        """input is all integers. size is height and width of gameboard, cells refers to the number of living cells the user designates to start the board game"""
        self.size=size
        self.cells=cells
    def createBoard(self):
        """input integers width and height. Output is a board of 0s"""
        a=[]
        for i in range(self.size):
            a.append([])
            for j in range(self.size):
                a[i].append(0)
        return a

    def updateBoard(self):
        print('update now')
        """initial board update to begin the game"""
        original=self.createBoard()
        print('create board')
        for i in range(self.cells): #number of cells = number of cell coordinates
            row=int(input('what row is the living cell in?'))
            column=int(input('what column is the living cell in?'))
            original[row][column]=1
        return original #the first gameBoard

class printBoard:
    """printing the board"""
    def __init__(self,upboard,size):
        self.upboard=upboard
        self.size=size
    def pBoard(self):
        graf=''
        for i in range(self.size):
            graf+='\n'
            for j in range(self.size):
               graf+=str(self.upboard[i][j])
        print(graf)


class checkState:
    """this class will update the neighboring cells according to Jon Conway's rules of the game of life"""
    def __init__(self,board, upboard, size):#updateBoard will provide the initial living cells, but this will selfupdate
        self.board=board
        self.upboard=upboard
        self.size=size

    def rules(self): #cycle through array coordinates of the board and apply rules to each coordinate
        a=self.board
        b=self.upboard
        print(a)
        neighborcells=[[i,j] for j in range(len(a[i])) for i in range(len(a))]
        #print('neighborcells are '+str(neighborcells)) #a list of board coordinates

        ###FIRST LOOP###
        for x in range(len(neighborcells)):
            totalalive=0
            ninecells=[[neighborcells[x][0]+w,neighborcells[x][1]+h] for h in range(-1,2) for w in range(-1,2)]
            print('\nthe ninecells are '+ str(ninecells))
            z=neighborcells[x] #original coord

            for cell in ninecells: #counts total number of live cells for each of the neighboring cooridnates
                    xn=cell[0] #row
                    yn=cell[1] #column
                    if cell==z: #convert original coordinate points into nested array checker
                        checkifOne=self.board[xn][yn]

                    if (xn in list(range(size)) and yn in list(range(size))):

                        if self.board[xn][yn]==1: 
                            totalalive+=1
            print('the origboard is ' +str(self.board))
            print('total number of live neighboring cells for original coordinate ' + str(z)+ ' is ' +str(totalalive))

            #DONT RUN UNTIL YOU ADD UP THE TOTAL NUMBER OF CELLS

            if (checkifOne!=1):
                print('the original coordinate is '+str(z))
                #print('running live or die function')
                print('the cell '+ str(z) + ' has ' + str(totalalive) + ' live neighbors')
                self.liveordie(totalalive,neighborcells[x]) #pass the array of alive cells

            else: #SUBTRACT ONE LIVE CELL IF 
                totalalive -= 1
                print('Subtracting 1 live cell from the original: the cell '+ str(z) + ' has ' + str(totalalive) + ' live neighbors')
                self.liveordie(totalalive,neighborcells[x])

                    #else:
                        #print('the coordinate ' + str(xn) + 'by ' + str(yn) + 'is not within the board boundaries')
        print('upboard is ' +str(self.upboard))
        print('origboard is '+str(self.board))
        return self.upboard

    def liveordie (self,alive,originalcoord):
        xo=originalcoord[0]
        yo=originalcoord[1]
        if alive > 3:
            self.upboard[xo][yo]=0 #UPDATES original board
            print('Im too crowded im dead :(')            
        elif alive < 2:
            self.upboard[xo][yo]=0
            print('Im too lonely im dead :(')
        elif (self.upboard[xo][yo]==1) and (alive ==2 or alive ==3):
            self.upboard[xo][yo]=1
            print('theres just enough im still alive :)')
        elif (self.upboard[xo][yo]==0) and (alive==3):
            self.upboard[xo][yo]=1
            print('perfect number of neighbors im alive :)')





### GETTING STARTED###

size=int(input('What is the size of your gameboard?'))
cells=int(input('How many living cells do you want to start with?'))

newgame=setup(size,cells)

print('OK here is your initial setup')

print('first  gameboard')
firstgame=newgame.updateBoard()#first  gameboard
#Print Board

print('this is out what the board looks like in the beginning')
startGame=printBoard(firstgame, size) #this is out what the board looks like in the beginning


print('print the board () refers to the instance we just created ')
startGame.pBoard() #print the board () refers to the instance we just created 


repeat=int(input('enter the number of times you would like this to repeat'))

x=checkState(firstgame, firstgameoriginal, size) 
print('checkstate is the original value of x: ' + str(x))

###MAIN LOOP###

for i in range(repeat):
    print('i is ' + str(i))
    newboard=x.rules() #returns a NEW board
    x=checkState(newboard,newboard, size) #saves the state of NEW board for the next iteration

    ###PRINTS THE BOARD###
    printupdate=printBoard(newboard, size)
    printupdate.pBoard()

    if i==repeat:
        break;
```

Comment: I'd be glad to help you with this, but it looks like there's a lot going on, and the program doesn't even run just yet.  Since you're learning, I think it's probably better to help you fix everything yourself, rather than just post a fixed version of your code.  That really goes beyond what we can do on this site.  If you can post a github link to your code, we might be able to work on it there more easily.  If you aren't familiar, here is a great intro course on [how to use git and github](https://www.udacity.com/course/how-to-use-git-and-github--ud775).

Comment: Thanks coralv, I posted it on github: https://github.com/st4rgut25/Battleshiph-Game/blob/master/Life.py

Comment: Perfect.  I could use more experience on github working with other users, so this can help me, too.  I see your code there is already different from what's here, so let's post some issues and get to it!

Comment: Thanks, I updated it by trying to copy the list using copy.copy() and list() after seeing a similar question on stackoverflow, but still got the same output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python